# In flex4 & as3 how do you change the button label dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, button, label

Is there any way to change Spark button label dynamically? When i click on it, i want the label to change. I bind the String to label and gives value for the first time, but even flashBuilder shows me that Data binding will not be able to detect assignments.
Here is my button:

```
<s:Button name="button" label="{butt}" x="5" y="3" useHandCursor="true" 
          click="start()" buttonMode="true" cornerRadius="5" 
          skinClass="skins.CustomButtom"/>
```

And here is assigment:

```
public var butt:String = "Start";
```

**Update**
Both answers work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the variable Bindable like this:

```
[Bindable]  
public var butt:String = "Start";
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable to have buttons with changing labels.
Even if you must, it is preferable to change the `label` property directly instead of introducing a binding because Flash Player needs to instantiate extra listeners for bound variables.
In this case, a binding is required only if you are going to be changing the label frequently.

Without the bindable, you might have noticed that Flash will assign the value `"Start"` to the label of the button (generally, the value of the bound variable at the time of creation of the button).

Comment: well i have only one button in application, i hope it wont be a problem. But for good coding practising how can i change label property directly?

Comment: You can write `myButton.label="Click Me!"`.
All objects declared in mxml are scoped to `public`, so you can even do this from another class.

Comment: Thank, thats actually really helped and ill use it. i been trying that but somehow it wasnt worked before, maybe its just was because of my newbie nature acting with all this stuff. I can say, its really confusing language after usual web languages like php and javascript.

Comment: Ah, well, you'll get used to it, we all do :) Best of luck